# Matlab , matrix operations

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have for example this matrix

```
A=[ 
  11  15   19   13
  12  16   0    114
  13  17   111  115
  14  18   112  116
  ];
```

I want to find nonzero elements of two matrix of indices:

```
i1=[1 3];
i2=[2 4];
```

The result:

```
B=A(i2,i1);
B=[12  0
   14 112];
```

index of matrix in A.

```
 index=[2 4 12];
```

So, How to obtain the indices without loop?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you define those indices? Why is index 10 missing?

Comment: You need to do `B = A(i2,i1)` to get the matrix you showed, the first index is the row, the second the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a one-liner which is not quite readable of course:

```
index = find(diag(ismember(1:size(A,1), i2))*A*diag(ismember(1:size(A,2), i1)));
```

or alternatively

```
index=find(sparse(i2,i2,1,size(A,1),size(A,1))*A*sparse(i1,i1,1,size(A,2),size(A,2)));
```

and there is more elaborate and readable one:

```
z=zeros(size(A));
z(i2,i1) = A(i2,i1);
index=find(z);
```

Note that the first one-liner fails if the matrix contains `Inf` or `NaN` values because those values will be multiplied by zero, the second and third methods are more robust in that sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution:

```
% sub2ind does not work, use this hack instead
z = zeros(size(A));
z(i2,i1) = 1
ind = find(z) % get linear indices

%only keep the ones for which A is nonzero
ind = ind(A(ind) ~= 0)
```

Result:

```
z =
     0     0     0     0
     1     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0
     1     0     1     0

ind =
     2
     4
    10
    12

ind =
     2
     4
    12
```

Comment: Last line should be _ind = ind(~~A(ind))_

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more compact than Bas Swinckels answer:

```
I=reshape(1:numel(A),size(A));
J=I(i2,i1);
J(~~B)
```

Comment: Last line should probably be `J(~~A(J))`, otherwise you need another line to define `B`.